# the amount of questions generated by an app is based on the amount of tickets he/she has in a cart app. How could I make this work?

Tags: python, django

Hi I'm setting up  a site where a users can purchase tickets for a raffle. Before they get to be entered, they have to answer questions. the amount of go's at the question they can have has to be depended on the amount of tickets they are trying to purchase. If a ticket is delated or added from the cart so will the question. I have already created a cart app and the quiz app but I have an issue with conntecting them together. Any advice would be much appreciated!

Apologies for not adding code but there is just a lot. below is a snippet that adds the questions to the context

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(QuizTake, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['question'] = self.question

Now my question is could i duplicate the value in 'question' according to the values in cart? Sorry if this is simple, I'm still quite new to Django.

Comment: Without showing the code there is no real way for anyone to tell you how to connect the apps.

Comment: Yep, please [edit] a [mcve] into your question.

Comment: edited slightly, not sure if its helpful

Answer (score 0):

It would be really awesome if you put the code up so that this answer would be more specific, but from your description, I'd go about it like this:

1. Ask the user how many tickets they are trying to purchase and pass that value to the question app, use it to edit the number of question.
2. After they are done answering the questions pass the value of the number of questions they got correct to the cart app.
3. Use this value to limit the number of tickets they are able to purchase and then proceed to your normal checkout page.

Hope this helps, but it would be much better if you put your code up. Cheers.
Use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to guide you.